# Mageto 2.4.5 uiComponent html template not loaded

Tags: uicomponent

I am new to Magento, trying to do a simple block page

in `view/frontend/templates.clockroute.phtml` :

```
<div id="uic-demo-container" data-bind="scope: 'clockroute'">
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#uic-demo-container": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "clockroute": {
                    "component": "MzTest_UiComponent/js/view/clockroute",
                    "config": {
                        "template": "MzTest_UiComponent/clockroute"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

the file `view/frontend/web/js/view/clockroute.js`, laoded successfully, and i confimed it by logs, and contains:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function(uiComponent, ko) {
    return uiComponent.extend({
        _currentTime: ko.observable('Loading...'), // initail
        initialize: function(){
            this._super();
            setInterval(this.updateTime.bind(this), 1000)
        },
        getTime: function(){
            return this._currentTime
        },
        updateTime: function(){
            this._currentTime(new Date());
        }
    })
});
```

the problem is in `view/frontend/web/template/clockroute.html`, wasn't loaded and didn't throw any error, it just contain `<h1 data-bind="text: getTime()"></h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to get template like this:

```
<div id="uic-demo-container" data-bind="scope: 'clockroute'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#uic-demo-container": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "clockroute": {
                        "component": "MzTest_UiComponent/js/view/clockroute",
                        "template": "MzTest_UiComponent/clockroute"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

? If not please try to do it in that way. You should not only add template into phtml configs but also make sure that you are using getTemplate() function.